# Salsissimum futura erit - is this right?

Tags: vocabulary, translation-check, grammar-choice

I need this translation for an artwork

"future will be salty"

Salsissimum erit futura 
Salsissimum futura erit

it's a joke for an illustration of Diocletian announcing the salt as payment.

Comment: "Salsissimum futura erit" means "she is going to be a salty thing."

Answer (score 1):

"Futurus-a-um" is a future active participle, so it means "about to be". Futura is the feminine form, and must agree with a feminine noun, otherwise it implies "femina" (woman). And the neuter gender of your word for salty implies that whatever thing you're referring to is not alive.

The grammar of what you provide reads "She-who-is-about-to-exist will be an extremely salty object."

I suggest you use this: "Salissimum (erit) Futurum." In Latin, the to-be verb can be dropped, and it is often dropped for pithy phrases. I put "Salissimum" first, since you seem to be trying to imply that it will be EXTREMELY salty based on the -issimum ending, and putting words first emphasizes them.